# How do not make the _Layout render every time?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I created a test project of MVC3,and the project has only one layout of razor.
In the Layout I use a jquery to create dynamic menus,I just want get the effect is when i clicked these menu ,it should return different partial views in the body segment,and the layout menu should remember the menu state i clicked on the layout page.

But the result is ,when i click the menus everytime ,the layout will render again,and the menu state will restore ,how to resolve the problem?

This is my code !!! Can anybody help me?Thanks!!!

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>

                <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
                <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function () {
                              $(".sidebar1 dl dd").hide();
                              $(".sidebar1 dl dt").click(function () {
                              $(".sidebar1 dl dd").not($(this).next()).hide();

                              $(this).next().slideToggle(500);

                        });
                    });

            </script>

            </head>
            <body>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="header"><a href="#"><img src="/Content/images/logo.png" alt="logo" name="Insert_logo" width="180" height="90" id="Insert_logo" style="background-color: #C6D580; display:block;" /></a>

                <!-- end .header --></div>
              <div class="sidebar1">

                <dl class="nav">
                  <dt><a href="#">aaaaa</a></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">AAAA</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">BBBB</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">CCCC</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </dd>
                  <dt><a href="#">aaaaa</a></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">AAAA</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">BBBB</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">CCCC</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </dd>
               </dl>
            </div>
            <div class="content">

            @RenderBody()
            </div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Don't use the layout in your partial views?

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the layout used on each page if needed.
If you dont want a layout just set it to null.
Put this at the top of the page:

```
@{
  layout = null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

user,

where you have:

```
<div class="content">
```

you need to change that to:

```
<div id="content">
```

you then need to target your partial views to update that div. This means that your controller actions should return PartialView(), rather than View(). Also, without worrying about any of the aforementioned, you could simply try changing your click function to:

```
$(function () {
    $(".sidebar1 dl dd").hide();
    $(".sidebar1 dl dt").click(function (e) {
        $(".sidebar1 dl dd").not($(this).next()).hide();

        $(this).next().slideToggle(500);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

there could be more required as you don't show the ajax code but I'm willing to bet that if you have followed standards in your ajax calls, then this will all resolve itself with the changes mentioned.